# Excel 2010: Best use of CASE or IF to define SAVEAS location (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

**Program:**  Excel 2010
**Experience:**  Basic

**Question**
I am wanting to save my workbook sheet (and generated .pdf) in locations dependent on a cell value, rather than writing 5 Subs, *I want to write one using either `IF` or `CASE`*.  I do have a static save location (dropbox), however I also need to save duplicates in the respective Cell locations.

I can't get the syntax correct to get either working.

```
Sub saveManID()
    Dim sDB As String
    Dim sMDocs As String
    Dim sMBus As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sSel As String
    Dim sMan As String

    'define file name
    sName = Sheets("Statement").Range("B52").Text

    'define location name
    sDB = "E:\location dropbox\"
    sMDocs = "D:\My Documents\"
    sMBus = "D:\location alt\"

    '---- Either IF or CASE to define the SAVEAS location ----'  
    If Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text = "3" Then
        sMan = "G:\location\folder3\"

    If Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text = "4" Then
        sMan = "G:\location\folder4\"

    '---- end ----'   

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sMan & sName & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xls",_  
     FileFormat:=52, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False    

    Sheets("Statement").Range("A1:G49").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sMan & sName & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


        End if
    End if
End Sub
```

I need to get the `Range("J2")` to define location from the cell value & I need to create the name based on another cell value.

The Sub runs fine if I exclude the `IF`, but it means I have to have the code duplicated and a button assigned for each value.

To clarify - the Cell Value `Range("J2")` will determine where the file saves to, in the example above it is in the `IF` statement, which does not work.

Comment: what is you actual problem and question here? it's unclear to me what you are asking

Comment: @mehow it's in the title and the description, I need to define the SAVEAS location based on a Cell Value (J2), and I need to define it using either the `IF` or `CASE` statements so that the SAVEAS becomes dynamic depending on the result, IE 3, 4, 5

Comment: For starters, as your code stands right now, it will never fire the `SAVEAS` command as it is currently set you to see if J2=3 and then J2=4. Move your two `End If` statements to immediately after each `sMan` declaration rather than after the `SAVEAS`. Personally though, I would use `Select... Case` if there are plans to add more to the list, with a `Case Else` catch-all to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix what you have written try moving your `End If` before your common code like this:

```
If Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text = "3" Then
    sMan = "G:\location\folder3\"
End If

If Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text = "4" Then
    sMan = "G:\location\folder4\"
End if

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sMan & sName & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xls",_  
 FileFormat:=52, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False    

Sheets("Statement").Range("A1:G49").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sMan & sName & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

---

Or like this:

```
If Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text = "3" Then
    sMan = "G:\location\folder3\"
ElseIf Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text = "4" Then
    sMan = "G:\location\folder4\"
End if
```

---

Or like this:

```
myVal = Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text
If myVal = "3" Then
    sMan = "G:\location\folder3\"
ElseIf myVal = "4" Then
    sMan = "G:\location\folder4\"
End if
```

---

To use a `Select Case` re-write it like this:

```
Select Case Sheets("Statement").Range("J2").Text
      Case "3"
           sMan = "G:\location\folder3\"

      Case "4"
           sMan = "G:\location\folder4\"

      Case Else
           'set sMan to your default dropbox location here
End Select
```

Comment: Just spotted this entry. Pretty much exactly what I was getting at and most certainly the answer

Comment: @Portland Runner Thank you, I have a few IDs that I will be adding, so the list will grow as the Database fills out.  I'm going with the `CASE` statement.  Great work!